# How to create installer with Innosetup which should not register the application with Add/Remove programs?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I want to create a installer using Innosetup which should not register the application with windows installer, This option i could see it in Advanced Installer.
If this option is selected it installer won't write any values to registry and will not appear in Add/Remove programs, it just copy files to the desired location.

This feature is required for creating portable applications

It simply works as a extractor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set either [`CreateUninstallRegKey=no`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_createuninstallregkey.htm) to block just the entries in the Add/Remove programs, or [`Uninstallable=no`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_uninstallable.htm) to disable all uninstall functionality.
Both of these have side effects like stopping the `UsePrevious*` values and `Get/SetPreviousdata`.

Note that the Add/Remove programs is NOT Windows Installer which is a different technology and an alternative to Inno.

Comment: This solution works fine, This is what i'm searching for.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This helped me alot. Thanks for the tip.